# Change your gamemode in Minecraft maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing an adventure map that I downloaded, and the only gamemode I can use is gamemode 0, which is survival. Is there any way I can change the gamemode? Or turn on cheats?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, Do this :    ESC > Open To Lan > TICK "Cheats" to be ON.
Then just do /gamemode (survival,creative,advanture,spectator)

Comment: @user121154 please mark the answer with a check if it answered your question.